# The best way of learning linux directories and files

Tags: files

As a Linux user, I'd ask how to learn the Linux's directories and files, since everything in Linux is a file descriptor.

I've worked with some distribution of Linux so I think I did understand commands enough.I don't know this is true or not,but I believe the kinds of commands which configure the system work with files,so understanding Linux's files may be a good point to make a firm understanding of it.

By the way,Would you mind guiding me ?

Comment: Just curious to who tried to make you think everything in Linux is a file?

Comment: @JacobVlijm what i meant is each file takes control of each part of it,doesn't it?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @JacobVlijm maybe I was fed by wrong concepts :)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141016/a-laymans-explanation-for-everything-is-a-file-what-differs-from-windows - as they say, "Everything is a file" is a bit glib.

Comment: @JacobVlijm it has a wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file Just missing a word: " descriptor"

Comment: @Rinzwind Ah, now I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

The official page is:http://www.pathname.com/fhs/
belive it or not, I know that page look ancient and ghetto, but that is the official page of the standard. The official version is 2.3.

As you may notice, the standard is not enforced, distributions may deviate form the FHS Standard.  It is a tentative guide.   For example: your usb devices most likely mount in /media but in RHEL and SUSE perhaps they mount in /mnt

the OS can put files where ever it likes, the FHS standard is aimed at making things less confusing for users, admins, and developers.

Comment: The Linux Foundation now handles the FHS, so it's official page is http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml. It will be part of the LSB, so any distro aiming for LSB compliance must adhere to the FHS as well.